# updating files while app runs on heroku

Tags: heroku, python-3.x

suppose if i open my heroku webpage, it update a file, like a database.

now i want to retrieve it.

i tried git pull, when done, i checked, it is the old file what i pushed last time.
i tried heroku run bash and "cat"-ed the file, it gives old outputs. :/

but i can assure, the file is getting update, coz if i output the file content through server, like if i request for a particular path on my address, it will show the contents of that file on browser, then it shows updated data.

i have no idea why is this happening. any clue ?

i am using python3 with wsgiref module.

Comment: When you run `$ heroku run bash` like I assume you're doing, you are spinning up a one-off dyno with your code. You can edit these files all you want, but that dyno is not server web requests, and any changes you make are only on that particular dyno, and are lost when you exit the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the dyno filesystem for persistent file storage (like databases). The dyno filesystems are ephemeral and changes are not reflected in the git repository associated with you app. Use one of the data storage add-ons instead: https://addons.heroku.com